# Find the location of the last cell that was used to create a merged cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, cell

There is only one merged `cell` in the `Worksheets` that i pull the problem is that i don't know where it ends because this varies. It **always** starts on `M1` and end it goes acrross `row1` it can go and merged up until `cell Z1`. But this varies from `Worksheet` to `Worksheet` is there a concrete way to find the `Column number` of the last `merged cell`.

For example if we have a merged `cell` in my worksheets. It will start from `M1` but how can i find where is the last `cell` that it is merged in `row1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the address of the merged area, say `$M$1:$R$1`:

```
Range("M1").MergeArea.Address
```

This gives the number of columns occupied, say 6:

```
Range("M1").MergeArea.Columns.Count
```

so this gives the address ($R$1) of the last cell of the merged area:

```
Range("M1").Cells(,Range("M1").MergeArea.Columns.Count).Address
```

This is the address of the last cell *in the first row* of the merged area.

---

If you actually need the column number then it is:

```
Range("M1").Column + Range("M1").MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
```

---

To complete the story, if the area occupies more than one row, then we can get the address of the last cell using:

```
Range("M1").Cells(Range("M1").MergeArea.Rows.Count, _ 
    Range("M1").MergeArea.Columns.Count).Address
```

Comment: Thanks @AndyG back at you in a flash i am at work now i will notify you in ~25 - 40 mins. Gotta go

Comment: Thank you my friend and sorry for the late response.